# Using twitter-bootstrap to position divs on larger devices in a 2 column 'newspaper like' order

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to position div elements using twitter-bootstrap so that on a smaller device, the divs appear in the order demonstrated:

small screen:

```
|1|
|2|
|3|
|4|
```

Larger Screen:

```
|1|3|
|2|4|
```

I though some pull-left and pull-right classes might do the trick, but no luck:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="well well-lg clearfix">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 pull-left">
            <div class="alert alert-success">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 pull-left">
            <div class="alert alert-warning">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 pull-right">
            <div class="alert alert-info">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 pull-right">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/90gf8bh9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically to re-order Bootstrap columns on different views you should use the column ordering `col-XX-push-*` and `col-XX-pull-*` modifier classes.

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

However as you're trying to re-order columns that overflow in the same row (ie using a row to display two rows of columns) this will not work. You might need to extend your current Bootstrap columns and add flex-box support for better column ordering.

**As seen here:** (at 4:10) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0i7Xb22zzQM

So for example, the following code will be used to reset the column order (having arranged it [ 1 3 2 4] in your code already):

```
@media (max-width: 992px){
    .flex-row {
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        flex-flow: column;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .col-1 {
      order: 1;
    }
    .col-2 {
      order: 2;
    }
    .col-3 {
      order: 3;
    }
    .col-4 {
      order: 4;
    }
}
```

### Complete Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7w90ftkc/